# What's the story behind the Imperial Warren?

Tags: malazan

I keep getting hints about the Imperial Warren being the old Kingdom of High King Kallor which he destroyed to say that...well, that he COULD. Krul says something about healing the hurts of the land?

If there is no relation between Kallor and the Imperial Warren, what exactly is it's history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explicitly explained during the intro of Memories of Ice.

The Imperial Warren was once the land of Jacuruku, in the time when it was ruled by High King Kallor. When K'rul, Sister of the Cold Nights and Draconus came to kill Kallor, the latter (Kallor) burned the whole continent along with its citizens because "if I can't have it, no one shall".

K'rul, shocked by the act, after cursing Kallor along with the others, he created a new warren and lifted/transferred the whole continent into this very warren (a.k.a. Imperial Warren) in order to let Jacuruku heal.